# Netty Proxy to duplicate traffic

Tags: java, proxy, netty, nio

I am exploring a way to duplicate traffic from a netty proxy to two servers.
i.e. instead of the general implementation:

> Server1 -> Proxy -> Server 2

I would like to do the following:

> Server 1 -> Proxy -> Server 2 and Server 3
>
> Server3->Proxy is dropped

Hence each message is sent to both server 2 and server 3.

I just have one constraint that the communication between proxy and server 2 should not be blocked because of server 3 (in case server 3 is slow etc.).

I am starting from the following code: https://github.com/dawnbreaks/TcpProxy

Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with netty, but the implementation seems highly optimal for my purpose. I would like to understand:

1. How to create a new channel for Server 3
2. Which API to override for communication to Server 3
3. How to read and drop messages from Server 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

saw your chat in IRC #netty.

A couple of things here. Your Proxy would need to have a server side that Server 1 connects to. Then the Server 2 and Server 3 need to either except a connection from the Proxy or you could use UDP (depending)  to receive data from the Proxy.

Netty has an example of a proxy server. This would work in your case and its really easy for the third part. Simply put you would use the existing example and open a new connection which would be to Server 3. Now what you can do is take both channels from the Proxy (Client Connections to server 2 and 3) Put them in a channel group and write one time to two servers!. My example code that is edit will... allow communications from server 1 to server 2 through the proxy mutually and allow for mutual talk while server 3 only can receive data but if server 3 replies to the proxy, the proxy doesn't do anything. You may want to add a handler to release buffers or handle data written back that shouldn't be from server 3. Also from here this should get you started but check out netty documents, api, examples and ppts they are super helpful!

I will attach some modified code to show you and here is a link to the examples.

[Netty Proxy Server Examples](https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/proxy/package-summary.html)

So for the Example you would edit the HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.class and just add a second Bootstrap for the new client for Server 3.

***Current Code***

```
41      @Override
42      public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
43          final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();
44  
45          // Start the connection attempt.
46          Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
47          b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
48           .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
49           .handler(new HexDumpProxyBackendHandler(inboundChannel))
50           .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
51          ChannelFuture f = b.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
52          outboundChannel = f.channel();
53          f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
54              @Override
55              public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
56                  if (future.isSuccess()) {
57                      // connection complete start to read first data
58                      inboundChannel.read();
59                  } else {
60                      // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
61                      inboundChannel.close();
62                  }
63              }
64          });
65      }
```

***Edited Code***

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;

/*
 * Copyright 2012 The Netty Project
 *
 * The Netty Project licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
 * version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
package io.netty.example.proxy;

import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor;

public class HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private final String remoteHost;
    private final int remotePort;

    // As we use inboundChannel.eventLoop() when buildling the Bootstrap this does not need to be volatile as
    // the server2OutboundChannel will use the same EventLoop (and therefore Thread) as the inboundChannel.
    private Channel server2OutboundChannel;
    private Channel server3OutboundChannel;

    // TODO You should change this to your own executor
    private ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

    public HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler(String remoteHost, int remotePort) {
        this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
        this.remotePort = remotePort;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

        // Start the connection attempt to SERVER 3
        Bootstrap server3Bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        server3Bootstrap.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
                .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
                // You are only writing traffic to server 3 so you do not need to have a handler for the inbound traffic
                .handler(new DiscardServerHandler()) // EDIT
                .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
        ChannelFuture server3Future = server3Bootstrap.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
        server3OutboundChannel = server3Future.channel();


        // Start the connection attempt to SERVER 2
        Bootstrap server2Bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        server2Bootstrap.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
                .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
                .handler(new HexDumpProxyBackendHandler(inboundChannel))
                .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
        ChannelFuture server2Future = server2Bootstrap.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
        server2OutboundChannel = server2Future.channel();
        server2Future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    // connection complete start to read first data
                    inboundChannel.read();
                } else {
                    // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
                    inboundChannel.close();
                }
            }
        });

        // Here we are going to add channels to channel group to save bytebuf work
        channels.add(server2OutboundChannel);
        channels.add(server3OutboundChannel);
    }

    // You can keep this the same below or use the commented out section
    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        // You need to reference count the message +1
        msg.retain();
        if (server2OutboundChannel.isActive()) {
            server2OutboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                    if (future.isSuccess()) {
                        // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                        ctx.channel().read();
                    } else {
                        future.channel().close();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        if (server3OutboundChannel.isActive()) {
            server3OutboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                    if (future.isSuccess()) {
                        // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                        ctx.channel().read();
                    } else {
                        future.channel().close();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        // Optional to the above code instead channel writing automatically cares for reference counting for you
//        channels.writeAndFlush(msg).addListeners(new ChannelFutureListener() {
//
//            @Override
//            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
//                if (future.isSuccess()) {
//                    // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
//                    ctx.channel().read();
//                } else {
//                    future.channel().close();
//                }
//            }
//        });
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        if (server2OutboundChannel != null) {
            closeOnFlush(server2OutboundChannel);
        }
        if (server3OutboundChannel != null) {
            closeOnFlush(server3OutboundChannel);
        }


        // Optionally can do this
//        channels.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        closeOnFlush(ctx.channel());
    }

    /**
     * Closes the specified channel after all queued write requests are flushed.
     */
    static void closeOnFlush(Channel ch) {
        if (ch.isActive()) {
            ch.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }
}
```

***Discard Handler***

This could be added to the server 3 as a handler to discard anything written to the proxy by Server 3. By default SimpleInboundHandlers will discard messages after they are handled through decrementing the reference count.

[Discard Handler Code](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/discard/DiscardServerHandler.html)

Comment: does this automatically ensure that if server 3 is blocked, or has a slow-down it will not impact or slowdown communication between server 1 -> server 2?

Comment: The only additional load is data is leaving your socket to server 3 in addition to server 2. Internally processing using the channel group should not effect performance much. Server 3 could still technically write to the Proxy, but the data wont be handled. You could insert a discard handler. Edited the answer to include a discard handler for the connection on the proxy to server 3, now all data from server 3 is discarded if it writes to the proxy.

Comment: Sorry just for clarification, in the communication of data from server 1 -> server 2... is it the following server 1-> write(server 2) then write (server 3)... in this case write(server3) if it's blocked because server 3 is slow in receiving data (TCP sending is typically throttled if receiving server is slow), will it impact write(server2), in the next iteration when more data comes. Essentially I do not want any slowdown on server 3 to throttle the communication to server 1...

Comment: server 3 is supposed to be like a debug server, the data can be dropped etc. if it's getting blocked but it should not slowdown communication to server 2 which is production server. -> That is the idea

Comment: Server 2 and Server 3 writing are almost instantaneously together. Writing the data out is not a time consuming evolution. Server 3 you can do whatever with the data when you receive it. If you are using NIO and a multi threaded eventloop group then the writes should not block each other as the writes would be handled by separate threads concurrently.

Comment: I just took your code and the rest of the hex dump code, and tried to run the proxy, there is communication from the server 1 to server 2, but no communication to server 3. Could you please check. Also which line in particular prints the hex values in System.out?  I have put the code in https://github.com/nipunarora/nettyDuplicator

Comment: I also added a README to run the test which shows no communication to server 3: https://github.com/nipunarora/nettyDuplicator/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I think the key might be msg.retain(), I cannot resolve msg.retain(), I am guessing I need to cast the message to something else? I understand there is a reference count mantined and flush to server to will decrease it to zero so no message will be left to send to server 3 if this is not done. What should I typecast it to?

Comment: I have made an edit in the code. The message object needs to be typecasted to "ByteBuf" which allows us to retain()

Comment: I have the proxy that you have given working however it does not solve the problem that I stated for not blocking communication from server1 -> server 2.... To test this, I put a sleep in server 3. Once the client connects, and  after the first message was sent to server 2 further messages were blocked till sleep was finished in server 3

Comment: If configured right the Proxy should not block at all. Also the msg does have to have a retain(); UNLESS you use channel groups to flush the message to multiple channels at one time, channel groups the internal code does the retain for you. Where are you putting the sleep at? I looked at your source and did not see anything sleeping?

Comment: You also do not need to typecast if you use inheritance correctly on the examples. You might want to dive deeper into Netty Channel Handlers and see how they work and according to the API linked, you should have to manually call release on the message. Also take a look at ReferenceCountUtil.class https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelIoundHandlerAdapter.html ...  https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/ReferenceCountUtil.html ... Anyways Not sure how else I can help you answer your question here without you learning some more about Netty.

Comment: thanks so much for the assist. There was a mistake on my part, I can see communications continuing on server 2 despite a "sleep"/"slowdown" in server 3. I still need to understand the specifics of how the channel.read() works, which I will post in a separate question.

Comment: At a high level what I do not understand is if communications to server 2 and server 3 are happening in parallel, and server 3 is blocked or is sleeping, then I assume that all the packets being sent will be saved in server 3's TCP buffer? What happens when this buffer is full? Normally TCP message sending is throttled if server 3 is slow, but how would that play out here?

Comment: They will be saved in Server 3s buffer. Not sure how that would play out, depends on the OS and Server3. You can always your self write a throttle code on the proxy that queues messages and then you have a some scheduled thread to write them, but this would slowly consume the Proxies memory unless you write in a drop method. I.E. You can add the msg's to a queue and track the data size as you put it in the queue, drop them if queue is to full, then when you write you can write X amount of bytes from quad Just throwing an idea out.

Comment: this is exactly what the idea was, and I have an implementation with regular Socket I/O in Java. However, I found the proxy itself to be slow, which is why I switched to netty after finding it to be much faster.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have posted another question to discuss the thread model - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744627/thread-model-for-proxy-with-duplication-in-netty

Comment: If server 3 is actually sending to TCP buffer and not to an internal buffer then -  read for communication to Server 2 thread has to be blocked or alternatively write to Server 3 should throw an exception otherwise I do not see how forward progress can be maintained without an internal buffer. I saw in the API docs, that each channel maintains a bytebuf array which has a max capacity of MAX_INT and can be specified - does this not mean there is an internal buffer?