# Thread model for proxy with duplication in Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, proxy, netty

I want to understand the netty thread model and how messages are forwarded to outbound channels.

**The goal of my application is as follows**:

Essentially, I am trying to design a proxy which duplicates traffic from Server1 to both Server 2 and Server 3 such that:

1. Data is sent from Server 1 to proxy and from proxy to server 2 and server 3
2. All response from Server 3 is dropped
3. Any slowdown in Server 3 should not impact communication between Server 1 and Server 2.
4. Packets being sent to server 3 can be dropped if there is slowdown in server 3

**I already have working code for 1, 2 and possibly 3**

The code works by opening two connections to server 2 and to server 3, the channel read then follows as shown below by communicating to both server 2 and server 3:

**The problem I want to understand is as follows:**
From my tests I ran some simple echo client servers, and I can see that if I block read() attempts in server 3, it does not block the communication to server 2. 
However, this seems strange-

**Is there an internal buffer mantained which keeps the data being sent to server 3 (since server 3 is blocked)? If so, how can one specify the size of this buffer? If there is no buffer and communication to server 3 is blocked, then how can server 2 continue communicating, given they are reading from the same I/O channel?**

- Normal TCP throttles if there is slow-down in the receiver and even blocks the sending if receiving is blocked
- If server 3 is actually sending to TCP buffer and not to an internal buffer then read for communication to Server 2 thread has to be eventually blocked when the buffer becomes full, or alternatively write to Server 3 should throw an exception otherwise I do not see how forward progress can be maintained without an internal buffer.
- I saw in the API docs, that each channel maintains a bytebuf array which has a max capacity of MAX_INT and can be specified - does this not mean there is an internal buffer?
- Finally, I would like to understand or get suggestions on how this can be modified to add a queue/pipe or a user-defined buffer for sending packets to Server 3 or dropping them if the queue reaches a certain size.

The following are the relevant code snippets

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object buf) {
    // You need to reference count the message +1
    ByteBuf msg  = (ByteBuf)buf;
    msg.retain();

    if (server2OutboundChannel.isActive()) {
        server2OutboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                    ctx.channel().read();
                } else {
                    future.channel().close();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if (server3OutboundChannel.isActive()) {
        server3OutboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg)
                .addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                    //No. of bytes before unwritable does not decrease if server 3 is blocked
                    //                        System.out.println(server3OutboundChannel.bytesBeforeUnwritable());

                    ctx.channel().read();
                } else {
                    future.channel().close();
                }
            }
        });
    }


@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

    // Start the connection attempt to SERVER 2
    Bootstrap server2Bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    server2Bootstrap.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop()).channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
            .handler(new DuplicatorBackendHandler(inboundChannel))
            .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
    ChannelFuture server2Future = server2Bootstrap.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);

    server2OutboundChannel = server2Future.channel();
    server2Future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
            if (future.isSuccess())
                inboundChannel.read();
            else 
                inboundChannel.close();
        }
    });

    // Start the connection attempt to SERVER 3
    Bootstrap server3Bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    server3Bootstrap.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop()).channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
            .handler(new DiscardServerHandler())
            .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
    ChannelFuture server3Future = server3Bootstrap.connect(remoteHost2, remotePort2);
    server3OutboundChannel = server3Future.channel();

}
```